# Why doesn't MySQL include a decent migration tool anymore?

Tags: mysql, migration

MySQL used to have a Migration Toolkit, to make it easier to import from SQL Server and get started with MySQL as a production platform. That has been discontinued as a product. We were promised that an equivalent product would be added to the newer MySQL Workbench, but that has not happened.

It strikes me as a bizarre business decision, by the MySQL team, to put an extra barrier in the way of people who are considering moving from an MS-stack to a LAMP-stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate Data from MSSQL using PHPMyAdmin Web Interface!
Check [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)!

To install it on your LAMP-Stack (if you don't have it already), type this on server:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and Voilá!
:)

Comment: The function to Import data from CSV and SQL may be useful, I'll have to install this and see what it expects for the SQL option (hoping it is a set of "INSERT TABLENAME VALUES ( .....)" ) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, migration toolkit was **awesome**.

But still they support the import/export in mysql workbench.

Checkout here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-server-administration-manage-data-import-export.html

Comment: That import/export in mysql workbench might be useful, but I guess only if we're moving data between MySQL servers?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a strange move indeed...

You will find several tools suggested under "Migration Tools" here: [dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html).

Answer (score 0):

Latest MySQL moves look like the typical management decisions based upon marketing rather than actual software capabilities. The company has been through several owners in a few years and the last one, Oracle, has a strong will to make money out of it. (They are even making money out of Sun Microsystems!) MySQL used to have a bunch of poorly maintained GUI tools with a widely variable quality level. That's okay for most users but it scares away companies, which are the type of users that are willing to pay. Creating a single suite out of it looks like an intelligent move in the long term but they probably lack resources to speed up things and they want results now.

Right now, you can still find the old tools if you dig into the [archives section](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) from the download page. You'd better grab your copy before they change their mind. ;-)